# FB Login not working with React Native iOS v13+

Tags: ios, facebook, react-native, facebook-login, react-native-fbsdk

I've a project with following configuration.

```
"react": "16.8.3",
"react-native": "0.59.9",
"react-native-fbsdk": "^0.8.0"
```

I've setup *Facebook login* successfully with manually installed SDK components (i.e. FBSDK Core, Login, Share, ...). It worked completely fine with *Android* and *iOS v12* but since iOS updated to v13, it is having Login `isCancelled` in iOS 13+. I tried to update FBSDK to newer version using pod but it caused duplicate dependencies error.

Following is the **error log** from `GraphRequest` on initiation

```
{
    ...
    code: "ECOM.FACEBOOK.SDK.CORE8"
    domain: "com.facebook.sdk.core"
    message: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk.core error 8.)"
    ...
}
```

And this is the error on `LoginButton` press

```
{
    declinedPermissions: null, 
    grantedPermissions: null, 
    isCancelled: true
}
```

I've tried multiple solutions available on *stackoverflow* & *github* like updating version, changing `loginWithPermission` props etc but nothing work for me.

Kindly give me a suitable solution with manually *updating the FBSDK* version rather than `pod`.

Answer (score 0):

use this instruction and change in your pod files 
"https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/"
to fixing this issue